# Node.js CSV module

Tags: node.js

I'm using a CSV module as in the example below.
I was wondering if there is a way to make sure that all the fields aren't inserted as strings, e.g. the number `1.23` is not inserted as string `"1.23"`.
It seems to make everything type `string`.

```
var csv = require('csv');
var q = async.queue(myCollection.insert.bind(myCollection), 50);

csv()
.from.path(req.files.myCSV.path, {columns: true})  
.transform(function(data, index, cb){
    q.push(data, function (err, res) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, res[0]);
    });
})
.on('end', function () {
     q.drain = function() {};  
})
```

Comment: *Everything* in CSV is a string, CSV has no types. The only benefit to not using quotes is in reducing the resulting file size. Sure, you might use the presence of quotes to *infer* the type, but that's super dangerous.

Comment: I'm talking about the actual module, is their some form of type inference option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In csv.transform(), before q.push(), you can convert fields using e.g. parseInt:

```
data.fieldX = parseInt(data.fieldX);
data.fieldY = parseFloat(data.fieldX);
```

You could also `delete data.fieldY;` or add fields `data.fullName = data.first + ' ' + data.last;`